# Page not completely used

Tags: vertical-alignment, footer

I realized in my document (book class, \flushbottom by default) that not all pages are equally stretched until the bottom. At some points, where at the next page starts a new section, the text before ends not exactly at the bottom, more white space than it should be is there. Interesting, if I add one line, to stretch the content, rather the text moves to the next page.

Does anyone know where the problem might be? It looks weird.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside, openany]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{indentfirst} % Identation after chapter header
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/} }
\usepackage[labelfont={bf},
        %belowskip=-10pt,
           %aboveskip=0pt
        singlelinecheck=false
       ]{caption}                           
\usepackage{romannum}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{boldline}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}

\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{same}
\usepackage[backend=biber,natbib=true,sorting=none,isbn=false,eprint=false,
doi=false,style=ieee,dashed=false,citestyle=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{number}}
\addbibresource{Reference.bib}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl} % List of symbols
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makenomenclature
\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Abbreviations}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing*{\section} % Spacing before/after (sub-) section titles
{0pt}{16pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}{18pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}
{0pt}{12pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}{10pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter{. }}{0pt} 
{\Huge\bfseries} % Title without "Chapter" but Nr. in front

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}


\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[acronym,toc]{glossaries}              % use glossaries-package


\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{15cm}

\newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{List of Symbols} % create add. symbolslist


\glsaddkey{unit}{\glsentrytext{\glslabel}}{\glsentryunit}{\GLsentryunit}{\glsunit}{\Glsunit}{\GLSunit}

\makeglossaries                                   % activate glossaries-package


\renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%  Change the table header
%\bfseries Sign & \bfseries Description & \bfseries Unit \\
%\hline
\endhead}
\renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%  Change the displayed items
\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} %
& \glossentrydesc{##1}% Description
& \glsunit{##1}  \tabularnewline
 }
 }



\geometry{
paper=a4paper, % Change to letterpaper for US letter
inner=2.5cm, % Inner margin
outer=2.5cm, % Outer margin
bindingoffset=.5cm, % Binding offset
top=1.5cm, % Top margin
bottom=1.5cm, % Bottom margin
headheight=15pt 
}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\rightmark}
\fancyfoot[RE,LO]{}
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
%\setlength{\headsep}{0.4 cm} % Spacing between header and textblock below
\setlength{\footskip}{15pt}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\fancyheadoffset{0pt}
\fancyfootoffset{0pt}
%\geometry{headheight=29.54742pt}
%\setlength{\headheight}{30pt}

%\setlength{\footnotesep}{0.5 cm}
```

Comment: Is your log complaining about underful vboxes for that page?

Comment: Hey, yes, actually throughout the whole document - a lot! Is that causing the problem? What might I do? Many complainings in my log. Even for tables and figures the Label is always the same, does that cause errors? Edit: I use many /par for my paragraphs.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle No, iam using /par. Is it better for the typeset result just to use a blank space between paragraphs, right?! I use \\ very rarely, if I want a linebreak. In the considered section I did not use it before the error occurs, or might it even occur due to following pages? Edit: Iam doing cross references manually. So, these underful/overful hbox/vbox warnings are my problems then, okay. However iam not sure about how I can fix them good.

Comment: It always only refers to line 1, and it says: Badbox line1 Underful\vbox (badness 10000) has occured while \output is active [] Edit: I wrote my thesis with Latex and iam new to latex, so I let \label. I do not need \label then?!

Comment: ah vbox so that;s not `\\ ` then. that is just telling you that the page is short (ie what you describe) as you have shown no code can't tell you why. is \textheight-\topskip a multiple of \baselineskip? If it is not then you can not fill a page with just lines of text as they do not fit in the space allowed

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I gave the code now. I dont know if textheight is a multiple of baselineskip. Edit: I think you might be right, that it is an issue with baselineskip (paragraph distance) and textheight.

Comment: as I guessed you have changed the page size with geometry making it incompatible with your baselines, try adding heightrounded as the last option to `\geometry`

Comment: It did not do anything, unfortunately. Edit: Now it occured at another place as well. \flushbottom does then even not work but I think its really a geometry problem.

Comment: Don't set parskip to baselineskip,  and don't set footskip outside geometry.

Comment: So, how can I define a spacing of parskip equal to baselineskip? Or what spacing you suggest rather?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  This looks like you borrowed someone else's template and don't quite understand what it does.  How do TeX's defaults not do what you want, and how do you want to change them?

Comment: I constructed with great efforts my own template, which may be a bit chaotic at some points, but it took me much time and many efforts.

Comment: I dont understand, if there is a underful vbox, if I add text, why it goes to next page rather than filling the considered page.

Comment: Edit: In \setlength{\parskip}, adding a stretch i.e. plus and minus, solved obviously my problem!

Comment: You should use @UlrikeFischer if you want to ping me. Why do you set manually \parskip instead of using the options of the parskip package? (And yes adding a stretch is the way to go).